# Redshift query to count metrics by 10 minute windows

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

*About the PostgreSQL tag, as you may know, [Redshift is based off of PostgreSQL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html).*

> Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2. Amazon Redshift and PostgreSQL have a number of very important differences that you must be aware of as you design and develop your data warehouse applications.

I have a table that was created like this:

```
create table purchase (
  user_id int,
  item_id int,
  t timestamp
)
diststyle even
interleaved sortkey(user_id, item_id, t);
```

And I want to execute a query which tells me the 3 most-active users (users with the most purchases) in a ten-minute window, and the 3 most-purchased items in the same ten-minute window.

So the results should look like this

```
+-item_id-|-user_id-|-window-+
| aaa     | xxx     | 0      |
+---------+---------+--------+
| bbb     | yyy     | 0      |
+---------+---------+--------+
| ccc     | zzz     | 0      |
+---------+---------+--------+
| ...     | ...     | 1      |
+---------+---------+--------+
| ...     | ...     | 1      |
+---------+---------+--------+
| ...     | ...     | 1      |
..............................
| ...     | ...     | 5      |
+---------+---------+--------+
| ...     | ...     | 5      |
+---------+---------+--------+
| ...     | ...     | 5      |
+---------+---------+--------+
```

where `aaa` is the most-purchased item in the first ten minute window, `bbb` is the second most-purchased item in the first ten minute window, and so on, and `xxx` is the user with the most purchases in the first ten minute window, and `yyy` is the user with the second most purchases in the first window, and so on. There are six 10-minute windows because I will be doing this over an hour-long date range.

I'm pretty new to Redshift, so unfortunately I don't have any existing SQL to show you what I've tried.

Comment: add script to fill up some data and I can try to help with the query for postgres

Comment: @VaoTsun Getting the data turned out to be too difficult, but I'm going to post the answer I used shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My requirements slightly changed, but I was able to create a function that completed my new requirements. My new requirements were just to get a count of all the distinct `item_id`s and `user_id`s

```
select count(distinct item_id) as item_id_count, count(distinct user_id) as user_id_count, substring(t, 0, 16) as window group by window order by window asc;
```

Not sure if others will have the same date format, but mine was `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`, so getting the substring for grouping by 10 minutes required me getting just the `yyyy-MM-dd hh:m` part, and then I just grouped on that.